# How to use some keyword in subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, keyword

Here is the link to my sql code
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/5Lecen1
I don't know why but this is giving error when I am running it in an online sql compiler. It is giving a syntax error but when I am removing the operator "some" it is working fine. This is happening only when I use "some or any" keywords in subqueries can someone please help me find out what am I doing wrong

Comment: please copy / paste the code here with the "code" format. it seems to me the == could be a problem in SQL but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but I used '=' also but it is not working

Comment: again, please edit your question and you might get more help.

Comment: SQL is a standard but many vendors do not implement the complete standard and most (all?) provide functionality and syntax that differs from the standard and from each other. It is generally a waste of time to write "generic" sql unless you understand the limitations and have IMO signficant experience. In addition, you are assuming your "online sql compiler" works correctly and you need to know what standard (and version) it targets. IMO you are wasting your time.

Comment: 1) Please tag a single RDBMS (MySQL <> SQL Server) and 2) Please ensure your question is fully self contained i.e. does not require us to visit an external link.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53f4d3710d9ee09da2b8ba8b216c5c70

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for SOME specifies the equality operator as '=', not '==':
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: Hey can you please specify where the problem is exactly it would be of great help